# How to reorganize array of objects with lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I've got the following response from my db:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select": true,
    "insert": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": false,
    "template": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Template 1"
    },
    "module": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Module 1"
    }
  }
  {
    "id": 2,
    "select": false,
    "insert": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": false,
    "template": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Template 1"
    },
    "module": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Module 2"
    }
  }
  {
    "id": 3,
    "select": true,
    "insert": true,
    "update": false,
    "delete": false,
    "template": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Template 2"
    },
    "module": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Module 1"
    }
  }  

]
```

So my `root` objects have two nested objects (`template`, `module`) + their own properties.

I want to convert my array in such a way that `template` should be `root` object, should have `modules` property with array of modules objects. `Module` object should have property `permissions` with  `select, insert, update, delete` props inside. As you can see `template` objects are duplicated. I want to avoid duplicates of `template` objects in my result array, they schould be merged.

So the result should look like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Template 1",
      "modules":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Module 1",
            "permissions":{
               "select":true,
               "insert":true,
               "update":true,
               "delete":false
            }
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Module 2",
            "permissions":{
               "select":false,
               "insert":true,
               "update":true,
               "delete":false
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Template 2",
      "modules":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Module 1",
            "permissions":{
               "select":true,
               "insert":true,
               "update":false,
               "delete":false
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How to achieve that with lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't lodash, but I believe simple things like this should be done without external dependencies.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select": true,
    "insert": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": false,
    "template": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Template 1"
    },
    "module": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Module 1"
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "select": false,
    "insert": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": false,
    "template": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Template 1"
    },
    "module": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Module 2"
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "select": true,
    "insert": true,
    "update": false,
    "delete": false,
    "template": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Template 2"
    },
    "module": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Module 1"
    },
  }, 
];

const reorgData = data => {
  return Object.values(
    data.reduce((newObj, { id, module, template, ...permissions }) => {
      if (!newObj[template.name]) {
        newObj[template.name] = template;
        newObj[template.name].modules = [];
      }
     
      newObj[template.name].modules.push({
        ...module,
        permissions,
      });
  
      return newObj;
    }, {})
  );
};

console.log(reorgData(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My framework uses lodash very often, is there any reason to do simple things without it or it's just your preference?

Comment: Mostly a preference, but that preference is based upon lodash being a little pudgy and there is now vanilla js to do what lodash used to provide. If you are already using lodash in your project though, you can help reduce its weight by direct import of the specific lodash functions used, especially if your project uses tree shaking.